# Complex polygon in ArcGIS Pro: Included "kitty-corners" and exclude floating polygons

Tags: polygon, spatial, arcgis

I am working with a very large dataset, so I want to create automated processes where little to no manual work is required. The photos below are examples of what the datasets look like visually.

[photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMy0y.png)
[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtiJh.png)

Goal: to include all polygons that are "kitty-cornered" (see lower left and right of polygon in photo 1) and exclude the floating shape (upper middle of polygon).

Process:

1. Used Multipart to Single part on polygon
2. Create Buffer (1m) and dissolve by all
3. Spatial join with point layer to identify unique ID of polygon with the point layer

Issue: the spatial join, does not give a unique ID to the floating polygon. I want the floating polygon to be associated with the unique ID because I would like to do summary statistics later on.

So essentially, I want a single part feature where floating shapes are excluded, and still identified by a unique ID.

example outputs:
[example generalized tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PN1s.png)

Additionally, is there another way to dissolve without creating the 1m buffer, while meeting the goals I have?